# How to list products by category in a view with cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, categories

I'm with difficulties with controller and view.

Two tables N - 1 relation

**Products:** ID (PK), Name, Price, size, id_Category

(154,shirt,20,M,333) 
 (155,hat,20,L,325)

**Categories:** ID (PK), Name

(333,new) 
(325,discount)

*What I tought for the View:*

```
<?php 
foreach($cats as $cat) { 
    foreach($prods as $prod) { 
        /* category info */
        if ($cat['id'] == $prod['id_Category']) {
        /* products info */
        }
     }
     /* a break between categories */
 }
?>
```

What I expecto to see:

- Category X

  - Prod
  - Prod
  - Etc

- Category Y

  - Prod
  - Prod
  - Etc

I dont have a clue about the controller, and im not sure about the view too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Containable

[Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is a behavior which allows you to limit/expand query results to the scope you define.

For example, this will give you a list of Categories:

```
// Pseudo controller code
$categories = $this->Category->find('all');
array(
    array(
        'Category' => array(...)
    ),
    array(
        'Category' => array(...)
    )
)
```

Whereas this will give you a list of categories with all of their products:

```
// Pseudo controller code
$categories = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Product')
));
$this->set('categories', $categories); // used in the view
array(
    array(
        'Category' => array(...),
        'Product' => array(
            array(...),
        )
    ),
    array(
        'Category' => array(...)
        'Product' => array(
            array(...),
        )
    )
)
```

In this way, the only thing necessary to do in the controller is loop on the categories and then loop on the contained products:

```
// App/View/Categories/index.ctp example
<?php foreach($categories as $row): ?>
    In category: <?= $row['Category']['name'] ?> we have:
    <?php foreach($row['Product'] as $product): ?>
        * <?= $product['name'] ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

### Conventions make life easier.

The [conventional](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) name for the foreign key to define the relation ship "belongsTo Category" is `category_id`

Named like so the product model can be defined like so:

```
<?php
// App/Model/Product.php
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Category');
}
```

If you don't want to change the foreign key - it's not a problem you'll just need to tell CakePHP which fieldname to look for:

```
<?php
// App/Model/Product.php
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'id_Category'
         )
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your great post! That `<?php foreach($row['Product'] as $product): ?>
        * <?= $product['name'] ?>` is returning some illegal offset. I think `$product` is returning as a string

Comment: The only way to display it without those errors is `<?php foreach($row['Product'] as $product): ?> * <?= $product ?>`

Comment: Just check what `$categories` is and adjust your code accordingly. There is no flat array to itterate over in the code example in this answer/using containable as shown.

Comment: Debug $categories result: `array ( (int) 0 => array ('Product' => array (fields)), 'Category' => array (fields)), (int) 1 => array ('Product' => array (fields)), 'Category' => array (fields)) ) `

Comment: Note that in the answer the find is performed on _Category_ - not Product.